# How to navigate javascript multidimenion array dynamically?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a 2 arrays that look like this:

```
vars arrayVars = ["s", "p", "o"]

arrayBindings = [     {
        "s": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://ss.ldm.io/" } ,
        "p": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/name" } ,
        "o": { "type": "literal" , "value": "ss" }
      } ,
      {
        "s": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://ss.ldm.io/" } ,
        "p": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/img" } ,
        "o": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://fbcdn-sphotos-d-a.akamaihd.net/o.jpg" }
      },
      ...
      ]
```

I want to be able to navigate the `arrayBindings` dynamically based on the parameter of the first one, basically:

`arrayBindings[0].s.value` gets me `"http://ss.ldm.io/"` but doing it in way like `arrayBindings[0].arrayVars[0].value` which deosn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's where the [] notation comes in handy:

```
arrayBindings[0][arrayVars[0]].value
```

```js
var arrayVars = ["s", "p", "o"]

var arrayBindings = [     {
        "s": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://ss.ldm.io/" } ,
        "p": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/name" } ,
        "o": { "type": "literal" , "value": "ss" }
      } ,
      {
        "s": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://ss.ldm.io/" } ,
        "p": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/img" } ,
        "o": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://fbcdn-sphotos-d-a.akamaihd.net/o.jpg" }
      },
]
                     
document.write(arrayBindings[0][arrayVars[0]].value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access object properties by using `brakets ([])` or `dot (.)` notations:

Thus, `arrayBindings[0].s.value` and `arrayBindings[0]['s']['value']` return the same value `http://ss.ldm.io/`

***[Read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)***

Now, looping over your two arrays, dynamically :

```
for (i = 0; i < arrayBindings.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < arrayVars.length; j++) {
        document.write(arrayBindings[i][arrayVars[j]].value);
    }
}
```